# using CheckedListBox in vb.net2008

Tags: vb.net

In vb.net 2008,  How To insert Multiple selected Data from Checkedlistbox to Database sql server 2005?

**My Code is**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 Cn.Close()
        Cn.Open()
        Try
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Module_Control_tbl (empl_ID,Module_ID) Values('" & ComboBox1.SelectedValue & "','" & CheckedListBox1.SelectedValue & "')"
            ComboBox1.Focus()
            cmd.Connection = Cn
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Assign Module Successfully to Employee")
            Form7_Load(sender, e)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox("contact to Your System Administrator")
        End Try
        Cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just iterate through the CheckedItems collection.

Furthermore, you should always use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Here is an example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Using cn As New SqlConnection("Connection String")
    cn.Open()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine("INSERT INTO Module_Control_tbl")
    sb.AppendLine("(empl_ID, Module_ID)")
    sb.AppendLine("VALUES")
    sb.AppendLine("(@empl_ID, @module_ID)")
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
      Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sb.ToString, cn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empl_ID", ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@module_ID", item.ToString)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End Using
    Next
  End Using
End Sub
```